# Why are my radio buttons not displaying?

Tags: 6, forms

I'm working on enhancing a search form on a site I inherited. I'm trying to add a radio button set to allow the user to narrow potential search results, but I cannot for the life of me get the radio buttons to display. The label displays, but the buttons themselves do not.

Here's the function in template.php:

```
function ismiv3point1_search_block_form($form) {
    $form['search_block_form']['#title'] = ''; 
    $form['search_block_form']['#value'] = 'Search mysite.org';

    $form['submit']['#type'] = 'markup'; 
    $form['submit']['#value'] = '<input type="image" name="submit" value="Search the Site" src="/icons/search.png" alt="Search the Site" />';
    $form['submit']['#weight'] = 2;


    // this is the new field I'm trying to add  
    $form['image_switch'] = array(
        '#type' => 'radios',
        '#title' => t('Image Switch Radios'),
        '#prefix' => '<br /><span style="color:#fff">',
        '#suffix'   => '</span>',
        '#weight' => '3',
        '#options' => array(
            1 => t('Images'),
            2 => t('All'),
        ),  
        '#default_value' => 1       
    );

    return '    
    <div id="search-box" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 0px;">'.drupal_render($form).'
        <div id="search-loading"></div>
        <div id="current-type"><a href="#" class="date">Sort by newest first</a></div>
        <ul class="content-types">
            <li><a href="#" class="date">Sort by newest first</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="relevance">Sort by relevance</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>';
}
```

Here's the rendered source:

```
<form action="/"  accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" id="search-block-form">
    <div id="search-box" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
   <div class="form-item form-text" id="edit-search-block-form-1-wrapper">
      <input type="text" maxlength="128" name="search_block_form" id="edit-search-block-form-1" size="15" value="Search mysite.org" title="Enter the terms you wish to search for." class="form-text" />
   </div>

   <input type="image" name="submit" value="Search the Site" src="/icons/search.png" alt="Search the Site" />
   <input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" id="form-17ad7cfea143f9acf10cca6602a02df0" value="form-17ad7cfea143f9acf10cca6602a02df0"  />
   <input type="hidden" name="form_token" id="edit-search-block-form-form-token" value="65a199ea9da3f7a52ed4c2693012997b"  />
   <input type="hidden" name="form_id" id="edit-search-block-form" value="search_block_form"  />

   <br />
   <span style="color:#fff"> <label>Image Switch Radios</label>
     <div class="form-radios"></div>
   </span>
        <div id="search-loading"></div>
        <div id="current-type"><a href="#" class="date">Sort by newest first</a></div>
        <ul class="content-types">
            <li><a href="#" class="date">Sort by newest first</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="relevance">Sort by relevance</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</form>
```

Any ideas? Is it because the field is being added after the submit? The reason for that is because the submit is a graphic (the magnifying glass) at the end of the search box; we want the radio buttons to be positioned below that.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form builder functions must return a form array, not a string, otherwise they won't work with `drupal_get_form()`. If you need to add markup before and after the form you you should use the [`#prefix`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/6#prefix) and [`#suffix`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/6#suffix) properties, or do it outside of the form function altogether.

Also the function signature for Drupal 6 should not contain the `$form` variable as an argument, but the `$form_state` variable instead. And you're currently setting the value (text) of the submit button to the HTML representation of a an `<input>` field which will never do what you want.

Try using code like this instead:

```
function ismiv3point1_search_block_form($form_state) {
  $form['search_block_form']['#title'] = ''; 
  $form['search_block_form']['#value'] = 'Search mysite.org';

  $form['submit']['#type'] = 'markup'; 
  $form['submit']['#value'] = 'Search the Site';
  $form['submit']['#weight'] = 2;


  // this is the new field I'm trying to add  
  $form['image_switch'] = array(
      '#type' => 'radios',
      '#title' => t('Image Switch Radios'),
      '#prefix' => '<br /><span style="color:#fff">',
      '#suffix'   => '</span>',
      '#weight' => '3',
      '#options' => array(
          1 => t('Images'),
          2 => t('All'),
      ),  
      '#default_value' => 1       
  );

  $form['#prefix'] = '<div id="search-box" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 0px;">';
  $form['#suffix'] = '
      <div id="search-loading"></div>
      <div id="current-type"><a href="#" class="date">Sort by newest first</a></div>
      <ul class="content-types">
          <li><a href="#" class="date">Sort by newest first</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="relevance">Sort by relevance</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>';

  return $form;
}
```

**EDIT**

Just a bit of extra info on how to do this with a form alter hook:

```
function ismiv3point1_form_search_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['image_switch'] = array(
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#title' => t('Image Switch Radios'),
    '#prefix' => '<br /><span style="color:#fff">',
    '#suffix'   => '</span>',
    '#weight' => '3',
    '#options' => array(
        1 => t('Images'),
        2 => t('All'),
    ),  
    '#default_value' => 1       
  );
}
```