# Where does redirect from default search to apachesolr_search occur?

Tags: 6, search

We're using the apachesolr_search module on our site. (This is a site I inherited fully coded, so there's tons going on that I'm not intimately familiar with yet.) We have a search block that has been customized (see [this post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27635/why-are-my-radio-buttons-not-displaying) for details; we did eventually get the radio buttons to display, although in a really dirty, non-drupal way.)

I'm trying to get the form values on submit. Forgetting for a moment the radio buttons, I can't even figure out a way to get the value of the search box. Obviously it's getting passed to the solr search, but when I look at the Net panel in Firebug, there are no POST requests, only GET. In my submit function (which does run), I've tried `print_r('$_POST')`, `echo $form_state['values']['search_box']` (where search_box is the element name of the actual form element), tried looping through `$form_state` and printing all key/value pairs... nothing. Not a single one of these returns anything.

Obviously there's a redirect occurring somewhere that sends the value of the search_box to the solr search module to build the GET request, but I can't for the life of me figure out where it's happening. I think in order to see the values of the posted form, I'd need to intercept the values before the redirect - how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm mistaken, there is no redirect taking place. Instead the [`hook_search`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21core.php/function/hook_search/6) is used, which will pass the search params from the url.

Comment: That's the problem, though - what I really need to do is modify the URL, but I can't seem to get the values from the form itself. If I have three form fields, and all of them are filled out, there should be a $_POST somewhere that contains all three field/value pairs. There isn't.

Comment: No, search forms don't use the POST method. They use GET and hence the variables are in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

The redirect happens in [`search_form_submit()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search.pages.inc/function/search_form_submit/6) with this line:

```
$form_state['redirect'] = 'search/' . $type . '/' . $keys;
```

You can override it in a `hook_form_alter()` like so:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'search_box_form' || $form_id == 'search_block_form' || $form_id == 'search_theme_form') {
    // Alter the form if you need to
    $form['something']['#some-attribute'] = 'something';

    // Add a submit handler if you want to alter the redirect
    $form['#submit'][] = 'MYMODULE_search_form_submit';
  }
}

function MYMODULE_search_form_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {
    // Redirect to somewhere else if that's what you're after
    $form_state['redirect'] = 'somewhere-else';
  }
}
```